# How to avoid notification Multiple times entering the same geofence?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, geofencing, android-geofence

In my coding I am creating the Geofence for some dynamic location from my server and the geofence is working fine, But I must not alert for the same fence more than once within 4 hours. How can i achieve this scenario is there any parameter for this?

this is coding i'm using for adding geofence

```
new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(String.valueOf(mallId))
            .setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER_EXIT)
            .setCircularRegion(centerLat, centerLon, Float.parseFloat(radius))
            .setExpirationDuration(GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION)//Expire in 10 years.
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the little info that you have provided, I can only suggest you to keep a counter which will keep track of the number of times you receive ENTER transition. Also, it wouldn't be a bad idea to think in terms of using a combination of DWELL transition and LOITERING DELAY.